# Artifact made by IntelliJ IDEA doesn't work

Tags: java, exception, jar, manifest

In my project I use VTD-XML.jar which is in the same folder as the main JAR. I build an artifact with the manifest: `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: vtd-xml.jar
Main-Class: Librarian`. But when I launch this JAR I only have an exception: [image] What is the problem?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @mabbas It's on the picture. I don't have any stack, as in IDE it works properly.